# Android View is not null, but casting to ViewGroup makes it null

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity that adds a new view `onPostCreate()` like so:

```
View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
((ViewGroup)rootView).addView(myView);
```

When this code runs, I get a `NullPointerException`. However, if I don't cast it and check the output:

```
View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
Log.v(TAG, "rootView is " + rootView);
```

I get the log:

```
1340-1340/com.example.app V/MyActivity﹕ rootView is android.widget.FrameLayout@414d1b48
```

Why does this happen?

EDIT: I forgot to add that `setContentView()` was called in the preceding `onCreate()` and I did call `super.onPostCreate()` before the cast

Comment: @ASP Casting to FrameLayout also gives a Null pointer exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting is not a problem, or else a `ClassCastException` would be thrown.
It seems your `myView` that you pass to `addView(View view)` method is null, I don't see any other possibility.
Make sure you've initialized `myView` properly.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `myView` is not null in the following line:

```
((ViewGroup)rootView).addView(myView);
```

Comment: My mistake. I falsely believed myView was initialized.